# How to remove latex-based tile adhesive

Tags: tile, removal, adhesive

A friend bought a house that has tiles mounted over original tiles and she wants to remove the new tiles to restore/reveal the original ones.

The over-layed tiles can be pried off easily enough with a chisel, revealing that they have been attached using what I believe is a latex-based tile adhesive - it has a slightly rubbery consistency, a dark gray color and is quite thinly applied.

What is the best/easiest way to remove the adhesive residue that won't damage the original tiles?